# doctrine2 entities don't have loadMetadata()?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, silex

I created some doctrine2 entities to go with my database and can create/access the data from the command line. When I move to a Silex app, I start to run into trouble. When I try to get the entityManager to fetch a record it crashes with the following error message:

"Fatal error: Call to undefined method Entities\User::loadMetadata() in .../vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/Driver/StaticPHPDriver.php on line 79"

My composer requires are:

```
 "require": {
      "silex/silex": "v1.1.0",
      "symfony/http-foundation": "v2.3.3",
      "doctrine/orm": "2.3.4",
      "dflydev/doctrine-orm-service-provider": "v1.0.1"
 },
```

Is there some step I messed when creating these entities from my database? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this problem has to do with the way I setup the DoctrineOrmServiceProvider. Initially, I set the type to php. The correct type for me to use was annotation.

```
$app->register(new DoctrineOrmServiceProvider, array(
    "orm.em.options" => array(
        "mappings" => array(
            array(
                "type" => "annotation",
                "namespace" => "Entities",
                "path" => __DIR__."/../lib/",
            ),
        ),
    ),
));
```